# How to separate json array and put it on a html table?

Tags: php, jquery, json

[image]["cus_AKIT4Rz6NHlKMa","cus_AKIP3muBIL95H0","cus_AKI1l8vRoFhUyK","cus_AKI0B1DHs2IBxB","cus_AKHxuw8UvlwH8v","cus_AKHx6iyvJJOwWe","cus_AK03kmAOGCziJ8"]

The data above is the result of the code below, it comes from a PHP array I created on Kuha.php

```
function StartRetrieve()
{
var a = $('#selType').val();

    $.ajax({

        type:"POST",
        url:"Kuha.php",
        data:'&Type='+a,
        datatype:'json',
        cache:false,
        success:function(s){
        alert(s);

        }

    })
}
```

how can I access each data and separate it?
Because when I use

```
for (var i = 0; i <= s.length; i++) {
$('#tb').append('<tr><td>'+s[i][0]+'</td></tr>');
}
```

the [" "] is included and it is printed vertically like

```
[
"
c
u
s
A
K
I
T
4
R
z
...
"
]
```

I want the result separated and printed horizontally

```
cus_AKIT4Rz6NHlKMa
cus_AKIP3muBIL95H0
cus_AKI1l8vRoFhUyK
```

this is the Kuha.php

```
<?php
function httpGet($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array('Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $output=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
     $output = json_decode($output,true);//only necessary if the result of $output is a json encoded array
    return $output;
 }



$Type = $_POST['Type'];
$url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/".$Type;

$array = httpGet($url);
$id = '';
 foreach($array["data"] as $a){
    $id .= $a['id'];
    $id .= ',';

 }
 //echo $id;
$a = rtrim($id,',');
$a = explode(',', $a);

echo json_encode($a);
?>
```

Thank you for those who will answer.

Comment: Its not a 2 dimensional array. Just use s[i].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var s = ["cus_AKIT4Rz6NHlKMa", "cus_AKIP3muBIL95H0", "cus_AKI1l8vRoFhUyK", "cus_AKI0B1DHs2IBxB", "cus_AKHxuw8UvlwH8v", "cus_AKHx6iyvJJOwWe", "cus_AK03kmAOGCziJ8"];
var tr = $('<tr/>');//comment this for vertical
for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
//var tr = $('<tr/>');//comment this for horizontal
  

  tr.append('<td>' + s[i] + '</td>');
  $('#tb').prepend(tr);
}
```

```css
td {
  background-color: blue;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tb"></table>
```

Use this inside your success function just remove the initialization of var s

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138802/discussion-on-answer-by-guradio-how-to-separate-json-array-and-put-it-on-a-html).